# Material UI v1.0 with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Is it possible to use Material UI v1 with TypeScript?

I installed it to project using `npm install material-ui@next --save` and got a lot of error messages like

> "TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member
>   'TableHTMLAttributes'."

Probably, it is a problem with data types. Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you have an older version of @react/types?

Comment: Problem fixed with the latest v1.0.0-beta.10.